# Can I go from 15.10 to 16.04

Tags: 15.10, 16.04

I presume 16.04 will be LTS, so I would like to ask if I installed 15.10 would I be able to upgrade to 16.04 without much in the way of problems.

Or if I installed 16.04 now, would it eventually become the release version?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You will be able to upgrade to 16.04 LTS from 15.10 or 14.04 LTS.

It is recommended to install a stable version.

And also if you install a 16.04 beta now it will become a stable release with the standard update mechanism.

But please take in account that 16.04 is off-topic at this site untill it is released.

Comment: So basically if I installed 16.04 now, then on the day of release run apt-get upgrade it will push me to stable? And yeah just trying to get a better understanding of the update process and it's a good example to base off given the status

Comment: No. An "update" will. There is no "upgrade" from 16.04 to 16.04. The "beta" is just a word for a not yet released OS. Nothing more. The only thing that happens when it is a beta is that is will get more updates during that time.

Comment: `sudo apt-get update` will only update the sources list. `sudo apt-get upgrade` will install the updated packages.